# Render Order (EffectComposer? or Z-Buffers?)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm building a network graph using Three.js (ie a bunch of nodes and interconnecting lines). I'm trying to set it up so the lines always appear behind the nodes (which are Sprites) btu I'm having lots of trouble.

I tried setting renderer.sortObjects = false and then creating the lines before the nodes but it didn't seem to work. I've also tried to use multiple renders, and the EffectComposer, but still haven't cracked it.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just one scene, you can set the depthWrite to false in the lines material and lines.renderDepth = 1